# How can the browser know the current AD user ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

Is it possible for the browser to know the currently logged in AD user without explicitly logging in? I want the code in the server to execute with the same permissions as the user in the browser. Is that possible or do I have to require the user to explicitly log on?

Context: ASP.NET, mostly IE 7, IIS 7.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If I remember correctly IE has a setting which when enabled will pass the current ad token to server when requested by server

Answer (score 2):

If you...

- use **Integrated Windows Authentication** in IIS
- in `web.config` where relevant
- and your users and IIS server are on the same domain

...then it is possible to pass credentials through the browser. IE (being Microsoft's creation) can do this without prompting, other browsers may still insist on users inputting their credentials at the start of a new session.

Comment: Also "Impersonation" is worth throwing into the mix: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

OK there are a couple parts to this question so I'll take them one at a time:

First, you would like to authenticate "without explicitly logging in".  This is definitely possible with Internet Explorer using **Windows Integrated authentication**.  Please see this article ([Internet Explorer May Prompt You for a Password](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063)) for more details on requirements for your environment.  You will want to enable this with ASP.NET Windows Authentication mode.

Second, *you want server side code to run as the client's locally logged in user*.  This is called **Identity Impersonation**, and you should read this MSDN article to show how to configure it: [Using IIS Authentication with ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also See: [MSDN Windows Authentication Provider](http://sdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Note: We use Windows Integrated authentication for our Intranet site and the seamless authentication works with Chrome as well as IE, but Firefox will prompt for a password.